# C++ bindings for python in ros 2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since boost is no longer used in ROS 2 , what will be the preferred method for binding C++ code with python ? In ROS 1, we were using `boost/python.hpp`, what is the suitable option in ROS 2.0 ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297466/c++-bindings-for-python-in-ros-2/) by [Skyking](https://answers.ros.org/users/31939/skyking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2018-07-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-16**:
I don't believe there currently is a default/recommended library or framework for Python binding with ROS 2, but I've seen people use [pybind/pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even though the core ROS2 libraries no longer use boost, you're free to use it in your own packages.

It looks like rclpy (the ROS2 Python client library) is using the cPython API: https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/tree/master/rclpy/src/rclpy , so that may be another alternative for you.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0